# How to reverse a string in java, Input is a ATGC, Expected output is GCAT

Tags: java, string, char

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CandidateCode {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = "ATGC";
        char[] temparray = input.toCharArray();
        int left, right;
        right = temparray.length - 2;

        for (left = 0; left < right; left++, right--) {
            char temp = temparray[left];
            temparray[left] = temparray[right];
            temparray[right] = temp;
        }

        for (char c : temparray)
            System.out.print(c);

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

**The current output showing as GTAC, but i need the result as GCAT. How could i achieve this.Kindly let me know what i have to change further. I couldn't get as of now i tried.**

Comment: Shouldn't the output be CGTA?

Comment: your right = right=temparray.length-2; is incorrect. it should be right=temparray.length-1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use `reverse()` method of `StringBuilder`

```
public static String reverse(String str) {
    return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
}
```

#### Use `for loop` starting from the end of the string

```
public static String reverse(String str) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        buf.append(str.charAt(i));

    return buf.toString();
}
```

#### Use `streams`

```
public static String reverse(String str) {
    return IntStream.range(0, str.length())
                    .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(str.charAt(str.length() - i - 1)))
                        .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

#### Use `char[]` with swap

```
public static String reverse(String str) {
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0, j = str.length() - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        char ch = chars[i];
        chars[i] = chars[j];
        chars[j] = ch;
    }

    return new String(chars);
}
```

#### Direct output to console

```
public static void reverse(String str) {
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Test:**

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(reverse("ATGC"));
}
```

**Output:**

```
"ATGC" -> "CGTA"
```

Comment: where should i give main funcion

Comment: it compiled successfully but throws please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: all methods in one answer..Xd

Comment: there is another method of reversing a string using a stack. (split into chars, add  to tail, remove from tail : LinkedList )

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
 String input = "ATGC"; 
 StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
 char[] inputArray = input.toCharArray(); 

 for (int i = inputArray.length-1; i>=0; i--) 
     output.append(inputArray[i]);

System.out.println(output.toString());
```

**Your current code fix:**

```
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

String input = "ATGC";
char[] temparray= input.toCharArray();
int left, right=0;
right=temparray.length-1;

for (left=0; left < right; left++ ,right--)
{
 // Swap values of left and right 
 char temp = temparray[left];
 temparray[left] = temparray[right];
 temparray[right]=temp;
}
for (char c : temparray)
 System.out.print(c);
System.out.println();
}
}
```

**Edited as per OP's comments:**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
String input = "ATGC"; 
int length = input.length();

System.out.println(input.substring(length/2, length)+input.substring(0, length/2));

}
```

Comment: It is very low performace of string concatenation in loop!

Comment: `output.Append(inputArray[i]);` there's no such method! Check compilation errors

Comment: it gives output as CGTA , but i want as GCAT

Comment: i got output as CGTA, but i want last two characters reverse as GCAT

Comment: edited the code. You dont need to reverse the string.

Answer (score 0):

This method reverses the string.

```
public static void reverse(String s) {

    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer(s.length());

    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        b.append(s.charAt(i));

    reversedStr = b.toString();

    System.out.println(reversedStr); 
}
```

But if you want last two characters to be reversed to get GCAT just modify above code like this.

```
public static void reverse(String s) {

    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer(s.length());

    for (int i = s.length() - 2; i < s.length(); ++i)
        b.append(s.charAt(i));

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length()-2; ++i)
        b.append(s.charAt(i));

    reversedStr = b.toString();

    System.out.println(reversedStr); 
}
```